# Http/2 server_push with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, http2

I have implemented a program to communicate http2 using NSURLSession of iOS9, And it can communicate with my server in http2.
However, I'm having a problem with receive [server_push](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.2).
I found ENABLE_PUSH value is 0 in their settings and there's no delegate in receive server push in NSURLSession...

・I think NSURLSession doesn't support server_push. Is this right?

・If it support server_push,how to use?

```
/**
It WORKS for post data and get response.
I don't know the code should be added here 
in order to get the server_push.
I suspect that NSURLSession itself cannot receive the server_push(;_;)
**/
- (void) postData
{
     NSString *urlstr = self.urlArea.text;
     NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
     NSDictionary *params = @{@"data":@""};
    //json to query
    NSData *query = [self buildQueryWithDictionary: params];

    //make request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:url
                                cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                timeoutInterval: 10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: query];

    //prepare session
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    //resume
     [[session dataTaskWithRequest: request  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        if (response && ! error) {
             NSLog(@"Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data  encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        }else {
            NSLog(@"ERR: %@", error);
        }
    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: Hi T_ms, welcome to SO. You should post your code, and detail what kind of receiving problem you get.

Comment: Hi J.Chomel,thanx for your advice:-) I posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I received following reply from support.

> iOS does not currently support this.

---

update

(@vin25 comment)

ios10 supports it.

Comment: Any update on this? Has support for this been added to iOS 10?

Comment: Found out recently that iOS 10 does support it. Refer to the WWDC 2016 video on NSURLSession- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/711/. I have tested it and its working great!

Answer (score 0):

I read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28094460/187606):

> The HTTP2 push mechanism is not a generic server push mechanism like
>   websocket or server sent events.
>
> It is designed for a specific optimisation of HTTP conversations.
>   Specifically when a client asks for a resource (eg index.html) the
>   server can guess that it is going to next ask for a bunch of
>   associated resources (eg theme.css, jquery.js, logo.png, etc. etc.)
>   Typically a webpage can have 10s of such associated requests.
>
> With HTTP/1.1, the server had to wait until the client actually sends
>   request for these associated resources, and then the client is limited
>   by connections to only ask for approx 6 at a time. Thus it can take
>   many round trips before all the associated resources that are needed
>   by a webpage are actually sent.
>
> With HTTP/2, the server can send in the response to the index.html GET
>   push promises to tell the client that it is going to also send
>   theme.css, jquery.js, logo.png, etc. as if the client had requested
>   them. The client can then cancel those pushes or just wait for them to
>   be sent without incurring the extra latency of multiple round trips.
>
> ere is a blog about the push API for HTTP2 and SPDY in jetty:
>   https://webtide.com/http2-push-with-experimental-servlet-api/

Comment: Thank you for your information! Could you tell me if you know NSURLSession support this or not?

Comment: yes.....and The HTTP/2 support is part of iOS 9, and thus won't be available on earlier OS releases.

Comment: Hmm...I can see that only iOS9 (or later ) supports Http/2... but I dont know  Whether iOS9's cocoa API have the  function of SURVER_PUSH...><